# DynamoDb Item size issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamodb table called `events` and i am storing all events information there.

recently i fell into this type of error.

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Item size to update has exceeded the maximum allowed size
```

**Can anyone suggest a solution to resolve this?**

Answer (score 8):

There is a record size limit of 400KB, this includes item size and its local secondary indexes. And this can't be increased.

Standard practice to store message in S3 and index in Dynamo. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-use-s3-too.html#bp-use-s3-too-large-values) is some documentation.

Comment: Exactly. I'll add that even if you could store the item in the table, there are plenty of reasons not to in any database.